# getting error when making a plugin in Unity for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, plugins, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a plugin for window phone 8 in unity. but i am getting following error when trying to port actual device.

```
Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output was:
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (bool)

  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespace (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.GlobalRootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.LoadReferences () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

this is code of my dll file

```
namespace Plugin
{
    public class PhoneActivity
    {
        public static string getOperatorName
        {
            get
            {
                string networkOperatorName = DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator;
                return networkOperatorName;
            }
        }

        public static void makeCall(string Name, string phoneNumber)
        {

            PhoneCallTask pct = new PhoneCallTask();
            pct.DisplayName = Name;
            pct.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
            pct.Show();
        }

    }
}
```

i made build on Debug in ARM mode. I used File-> New Project-> Windows Phone Class Library to create the project.

I search on internet and stackoverflow.com and i found thread this this topic but the solution did not worked for me.

your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found solution after struggling 2 days. The solution in the tutorials it self. You should use folder under Plugins Assets folder.This should like this `Assets/Plugins/WP8/custom.dll` file. Folder name and sequence is important.